# Types of adjectives/adverbs

Tags: usage, adjective

As is said [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/adjectives/types), there are three types of adjectives/adverbs in German:

1. Predicative adjectives: *Der Clown ist lustig*.
2. Adverbial adjectives/adverbs: *Der Clown springt lustig herum*.
3. Attributive adjectives: *Er ist ein sehr lustiger Clown*.

In English, some adjectives are only predicative, not attributive, for example, *sick*: *I am sick*, but not *a sick man*. Are there such adjectives in German?

Also, most German predicative/attributive adjectives can be used as adverbs, if it makes sense. But, probably, not all of them?

Comment: It’s not really three types of adjectives, but rather three different uses.

Comment: *Sick* is very much an attributive adjective in English, too. And one really should distinguish between adverbs and adjective in my opinion.

Comment: Wasn't in old times Turkey routinely called "The sick man at the Bosporus"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are lots of adjectives that are limited to one or two of these uses. In fact, most of the possible combinations exist:

- only attributive: *inner-*
- only predicative: *futsch*
- only adverbial (usually called adverb): *sehr*
- attributive or predicative: *schwanger*
- attributive or adverbial: *völlig*
- predicative or adverbial: –

Comment: I don't understand the first item »only attributive: *inner-*« Do you mean adjectives with the prefix *inner-*? Maybe like *innerhalb*?. If you mean this, then your statement is wrong. »Der Ball liegt *innerhalb* des Spielfelds« is adverbial usage. Maybe you want to add examples to your statements to make them more clear.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Adjectives are usually given in their form without ending (e.g. you would write _blau_ in a list of colour adjectives, not _blauer_ or _blaue_). However, for adjectives that are attributive-only, this form does not exist. In this case, it is customary – at least in texts for language learners – to give the stem of the word and use a hyphen to indicate that it is not a complete word. So what I mean is the adjective in, e.g., _innerer Bereich_ or _innere Unruhe_.

Comment: Maybe you want to add examples to your statements to make them more clear.